# Make Facebook plugin responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook

So I am using the new Facebook plugin (Page Plugin) and have a hard time to get it responsive on window resize.

I have set the option data-adapt-container-width="true", but that only triggers when there i a page load/reload.

Please se my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29zgc790/ (try it in exporer and if that dont work try my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/IPnjpJUXxkO4WTLFTTW0?p=preview) where i have set the start width for the plugin to max (500px), but I want to trigger a reload of the plugin when the container (window) gets smaller then the plugin at that particular time.

I am thinking about somthing like:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    //Do the reload of plugin
});
```

Hope you guys have an idea of an solution that can guid me in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after reading the documentation for the facebook web sdk I found this little function that reloads the iframe.

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse

That solved my problem, but @LucaGiardina hade a good solution as well but I think its always a god practice to use the built in functions if thay exist.

Answer (score 3):

Embed the iframe generated:

`<iframe id="facebook" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:page Facebook Social Plugin" src="http://www.facebook.com/v2.5/plugins/page.php?adapt_container_width=true&amp;app_id=&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FTlA_zCeMkxl.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df1ce7bfb%26domain%3Drun.plnkr.co%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Frun.plnkr.co%252Ff152208424%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;hide_cover=true&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmicrosoft&amp;locale=en_US&amp;sdk=joey&amp;show_facepile=false&amp;show_posts=true&amp;small_header=true&amp;width=500"
  style="border: none; visibility: visible;width: 500px; height: 500px;" class=""></iframe>`

Get parent width and set it into iframe and iframe's src attribute

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  //Do the reload of plugin
  var new_width = $("#facebook").parent().width();
  $("#facebook").css("width", new_width);
  var url = $('#facebook').attr('src').split("&width=");
  url = url[0] + '&width=' + new_width;
  $('#facebook').attr('src', url);
});
```

Comment: Have you tryed the fiddle in exploerer? I tryed out your code and it works for reloading the iframe but the snippet information is not resent and that means that the container wont resize.

Comment: Plunker works.. well i suggest to create an external file. 
Your page will load an iframe with all facebook code, and on resize it will reload that page so all the code you need.

Comment: A god point but I see a risk of making the page hevy if i need to load "two pages" every reszis.

Comment: Well you can do it on javascript and make it responsive ongoing without any reload.. or remove and re-add all the script it needs on reload.. or check if there are in fb developer to make it without none of this just triggering the function inside the facebook's scripts :)

Comment: Use just the iframe. You just need to edit the link into the iframe src.
Set the style width to start, it's responsive getting parent element width.
http://plnkr.co/edit/FtWEOnoltTrKmFQo7HlF?p=preview

Comment: That can be a solution, but I dont like that you are adding a second layer of ifram in the solution. See what I found in the documentation in my answer. I think it is a god practice to use the built in functions when they exist.

Comment: Yeah, it's better i guess.

Answer (score 2):

After a few days of trying to achieve this, I came up with a working solution!
I actually registered only to share it :)

1. Copy the iframe code of the page plugin here:
   [Facebook Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) (go to "Get code" and then click on "iFrame" on the top of the window that just opened.)
2. Paste the code to your ***html*** inside a ***div*** with class **fb-column**, then remove the **width** and **src** attributes (paste the value of the **src** attribute - the long link - somewhere else, you will need it later)
3. Add this code to your main **.js** file (credit for calculating the box size and calling the function goes to [Mugo Web](https://www.mugo.ca/Blog/How-to-make-the-Facebook-Page-Plugin-fully-responsive)

   ```
   function resizeFBPlugin() {
     //calculate parent box width
     var container_width = (Number($('.fb-column').width()) - Number($('.fb-column').css('padding-left').replace("px", ""))).toFixed(0);
     // set the src and replace the actual width with the calculated width. 
     document.getElementById("fb-column").src = //paster link from iFrame here. Be sure to keep everything as it is, only replace the number after &width= with container_width
     // it should look something like this: 'https://www.facebook.com....&width='+container_width+'&height=......';
     // NOTE: take note of the use of apostrophes and + signs
     //set the width of the iframe
     document.getElementById("fb-column").width = container_width;
   };

   // call the function on resize and on window load

   $(window).on('resize', function() {
   setTimeout(function(){resizeFBPlugin()}, 500);
   });

   $(window).on('load', function() {
   setTimeout(function(){resizeFBPlugin()}, 1500);
   });
   ```

That's it! You now have a fully responsive Facebook page plugin (of course, within the min 180px and max 500px width.

BTW, The Twitter plugin works perfectly. I have no idea why Facebook decided not to fix this... I suppose they don't have the money for the right developers :)

Comment: Hi, you don't need to calculate any container size because the plug in will take up the whole space of the parent. What you need to do is to reload the plugin when there is a window.resize with FB.XFBML.parse();

Comment: For that, you would need to embed the plugin using the JavaScript SDK method. I tried that and it doesn't work. The container is either too small or the plugin is bigger than the container. In this working solution I am using the iFrame embedding method, where the width of the container is specified in the src of the iFrame. That's why you need to calculate the width of the parent container and use the output of that variable.

Comment: This works great except you forgot to mention that the iframe should be given an id of fb-column (as well as the container div with that class) hence the getElementById("fb-column") parts.

Comment: You're calling `setTimeout` on every `resize` event, which will end up calling `resize` dozens of times if you drag to resize the page and you never clear the previous timeout. You need to install have a global variable for the timeout ID, e.g. `var resizeTimeout = setTimeout(..);` and in the `resize` event handler you would do `clearTimeout(resizeTimeout); resizeTimeout = setTimeout(..);`

Answer (score 0):

I have found out some solution but i think the best one is at least for me is that setting the parent tag of fb-comment-wrapper in a certain responsive then use facebook built in css data-width:

```html
<div class="fb-comment-wrapper">
   <div class="fb-comments" data-href="{{request.build_absolute_uri}}" 
   data-numposts="3" data-width="100%">
   </div>
</div`>
```