# Facebook Page Plugin - Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I need to embed a Facebook Page Plugin on a website.
According to the info on

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

it can be any width between 180px and 500px

On large screen I want 500px width, but on smaller it would need to something around 300px.

Now, there is an option which makes the `iframe` adjust to the width of the container, but that part of it doesn't work for me at all.

So, what I have is two iframes (one for 500px width, one for 300px), and using `@media` queries, I hide/show the correct one.

However, it still loads two iframes.

Is there an equivalent `<picture>`/`<video>` tag I could use, which would load only one, depending on screen-width?

Alternatively, what I am doing wrong with the `iframe`?

Below is the code replicated in jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nuy4r1gk/2/ <-- 2 iframes

As you can see, it works, but it's loading two iframes, which is far from good. If I use css styling (`@media`) on the iframe, it just cuts it off, rather that loading narrower.

https://jsfiddle.net/nuy4r1gk/4/ <-- 1 iframe with css

Comment: .grid is a custom class you have added?

Comment: Seems to work fine when you leave out the `width` parameter in the iframe URL ...

Comment: @AashiqRathnadas yes, it's a custom class I've added which uses CSS Grid.

Comment: @CBroe https://jsfiddle.net/nuy4r1gk/8/ <- here it is without width parameter. The FB feed is better, but still not as good as with natural, as you can see by the images. Compare it with https://jsfiddle.net/nuy4r1gk/2/. I tried it with both width paramets (in the URL and generetic iframe atribute)

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution when using the iFrame embed method. It works with any container width between the supported 180-500px

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52459262/10401291